# How to check whether the linux system using a large disk space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using VirtualBox. I installed a ubuntu system on it. At the beginning, I set default 8GB disk space. But it's not big enough so I want to add more space on it.

I used this way(add to 20GB):

```
VBoxManage modifyhd my_ubuntu.vdi --resize 20000
```

After I restart my ubuntu, I run these commands in the terminal:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs           256M  4.4M  251M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       5.3G  5.0G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.3G  224K  1.3G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           256M   48K  256M   1% /run/user/1000

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 19.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  5.5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  2.6G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1 55.5M  0 rom
```

Why can't I see the addition space under `df -h` command? But can see it by using `lsblk`? And, is it really that my system is 20GB available and useful now?

Comment: You've expanded the disk (sda) but the filesystem on it (sda1) is exactly as it was before. You need to tell Linux to expand the filesystem to use up the rest of the disk, or add another filesystem you can mount somewhere.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: @KenWhite Okay. I have asked them again on those two sites.

Comment: @paxdiabloYou are right. Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, the proper thing to do is to choose *the single most appropriate site*, ask there, and delete your question here. Multiple site posting of the same question is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have set the default option 'dynamically allocate space' when creating the virtual hard drive in VirtualBox. So at once you won't see that your .vdi file increased to 20GB. But it will extend with your usage.

You can use the 'Disk Usage Analyzer' to analyze the disk usage on your ubuntu system.